# How to parse a graphql response in flutter using flutter_graphql plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-graphql

I am post data using graphql mutation. What i want to do is parse response data and use on widget on my flutter app.

How can I get parse response data from graphql mutation
here is my code

`

```
class RegisterService {
  final String name, phone, email, password;
  final VoidCallback onCompleted, onError;
  RegisterService({
    this.name = "",
    this.phone = "",
    this.email = "",
    this.password = "",
    required this.onCompleted,
    required this.onError,
  });

  Future<Object?> sendData() async {
    String addData = """
mutation signup(\$signupInput: SignupInput!) {
  signup(signupInput: \$signupInput) {
    success
    message
    phone
  }
}
""";
    final variable = {
      "signupInput": {
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
      }
    };
    debugPrint("SendingData");

    QueryResult mutationResult = await qlclient.mutate(MutationOptions(
      document: gql(addData),
      variables: variable,
      onCompleted: (_) {
        onCompleted();
      },
      onError: (_) => onError(),
    ));


    debugPrint("${mutationResult.data?["signup"]["message"]}");
    return mutationResult;
  }
}
```

`

here is function
`

```
  void buttonPressed() async {
    changeStatus(true);
    debugPrint("$_isLoading");
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        debugPrint("Successful");
      } else {
        autoValidate = autovalidateModeOnUser;
      }
      var utils =  RegisterService(
          onError: () {},
          onCompleted: (() {
            changeStatus(false);
          }),
          name: nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
          phone: ("09" + "${phoneTextEditingController.text.trim()}"),
          password: phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),
          email: emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
          );
      var res = utils.sendData();
  
      debugPrint("${res}");
      globalKeyScaffoldMessengerState.currentState
          ?.showSnackBar(mySnackBar("utils.sendData()."));
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

`

I want to get the response and use it on my widget .
I am using flutter_graphql plugin.

here is the json result.

`

```
{
  "data": {
    "signup": {
      "success": true,
      "message": "Code sent to your phone successfully!",
    }
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert response json to dart  from this site : https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/
2. ClassName classObject = ClassName.fromJson(jsonEncode(mutationResult.data));
3. You can access like this :  `classObject.data.signup` and so on.

Comment: Can you share some code example so how can i do that ?